# How would you use tkinter to create a basic translator?

Tags: python, tkinter, translation

I have made the "GUI". I had a drop-down menu but can't figure out how to make that work. I tried using switch cases i.e.:

```
def language(i):
switcher = {
             0 : 'german'
             1 : 'russian'
}
return switcher.get(i, "Invalid language")
```

In my other post I've mentioned how I tried to make it:

```
def rustrans():
    word = entry.get()
    translator = Translator(service_urls=["translate.google.com"])
    translation = translator.translate(word, dest = "ru")
    label = tk.Label(root, text = f"Russian text : {translation.text}", bg="yellow")
    label.grid(row=2,column=0)
```

I tried using if-statements like:

```
if language(1):
    btn = tk.Button(root, text="Translate", command=rustrans)
    btn.grid(row=1,column=2)

elif language(0):
...
```

I do have my labels, entry etc but when I try to switch the language (I had a drop-down but that didn't work, when I would change the language in there and pressed the translate button it would still prefer translating Russian instead of German i.e.
How am I supposed to make it so when I change the language from the drop-down (I can bring it back, although I've removed it) and press translate, it translates the right language?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the problem is. You just need to associate a variable with the dropdown, and then get the value when you do the translation.

For example, let's assume the languages are defined in a global named `LANGUAGES`. The keys of the dictionary will be used in the UI, and the values are what is passed to the translator.

```
LANGUAGES={
    'German': 'de',
    'Russian': 'ru',
}
```

We can use the keys to populate a combobox, and then use the combobox value to get value to pass to the translator.

```
class TranslatorUI:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.translator = Translator(service_urls=["translate.google.com"]) 
        self.dest_var = tk.StringVar(value="German")

        self.dropdown = ttk.Combobox(
            self.root, textvariable=self.dest_var, 
                values=[str(x) for x in LANGUAGES.keys()]
        )
        self.word_entry = ttk.Entry(self.root)
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Translate", command=self.translate)
        ...

    def translate(self):
        word = self.word_entry.get()
        language_name = self.dest_var.get()
        lang = LANGUAGES[language_name]
        self.translator.translate(word, lang)
```

Comment: Yeah that's kinda what I wanted but was not at the computer to answer how my drop-down code looked like. Thank you for an in-depth explanation.